# Call jquery function from c# to dynamically load textboxes

Tags: c#, jquery, dynamic

I have a form with multiple rows of text boxes. I use jquery .show() and .hide() to dynamically add or remove a textbox.

In my codebehind, I retrieve a myReport object and based on the number of entries, I want to display or hide the right number of text boxes.

I can use .visible = true / false but that removes the element from the page so that the jquery functions no longer work.

I tried using

```
.class.add('visibility', 'hidden')
```

but even with this, the jquery .show() function fails to make the textbox visible.

Is there a way I can call a jquery function from code behind or an attribute that I can add to a text box to make it invisible and still work with .show() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("yourtextboxselector").css({'display': 'none'});
```

You can check the visibility using [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

```
$("yourtextboxselector").is(":visible");
```

You can set the display attribute in C# also

```
txtBox.Style["display"] = "none";
```

Comment: and then how can I check in jquery if css property display is not none

Comment: isn't that the equivalent of `$('selector').hide();` ?

Comment: @TP - use `$('selector').is(":visible")`

Comment: No. .hide() does not set display to none. it does some other weird thing. if you have 'display:none' or 'visibility:hidden' set, then .show() will not make the element visible for some reason

Comment: So here is my actual issue then. I call txtBox.style["display"] = "inline" in my page load method since I want the box to be visible. (they are all hidden by default) but the jquery function to hide them is in (document).ready() so it overrides what the codebehind did. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Do you want to make the textboxes visible or hidden after page load?

Comment: And also what do you mean by "hidden by default". Do you set that?

Comment: yes. i hide them by default. I found a workaround. From the code behind, I set the number of rows visible to a hidden textbox and the the jquery reads the textbox value and makes the appropriate number of boxes visible